# Need real time data source for wind direction and weather forecast

Tags: data-request, weather, real-time

Where can I get real time data for wind direction and weather forecast?

Comment: Hi, do you need some specific location? Specific format?

Comment: I don`t have any specific location in mind.. in fact anything will do for now. And format needs to be something major data mining tools can handle.

Comment: Ok cool, I am working on releasing french (and worldwide after that) weather forecast 0-36h as a JSON API. For the moment most of the data available are in Grib/Grib2 format which is quite unusual to use.
The data will be updated 4times per day. I'll post everything below as soon as it's live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get wind speed & direction from [METAR files](http://www.aviationweather.gov/metar), which every open airport should be publishing.

I don't know if forecasts are as standardized.  I'm used to looking at NOAA's [National Weather Service](http://www.weather.gov/organization/), but there might be better services for non-U.S. locations.

Comment: I should also mention -- the wind speed/direction info might have some variability information in it -- see http://www.moratech.com/aviation/metar-class/metar-pg6.html#Coding